# Calculate summary statistic by category and filter - efficient code?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, filter, pandas-groupby

I have the two following dataframes.

df1:

```
  code           name          region
0  AFG    Afghanistan     Middle East
1  NLD    Netherlands  Western Europe
2  AUT        Austria  Western Europe
3  IRQ           Iraq     Middle East
4  USA  United States   North America
5  CAD         Canada   North America
```

df2:

```
   code  year  gdp per capita
0   AFG  2010          547.35
1   NLD  2010        44851.27
2   AUT  2010         3577.10
3   IRQ  2010         4052.06
4   USA  2010        52760.00
5   CAD  2010        41155.32
6   AFG  2015          578.47
7   NLD  2015        45175.23
8   AUT  2015         3952.80
9   IRQ  2015         4688.32
10  USA  2015        56863.37
11  CAD  2015        43635.10
```

I want to return the `code`, `year`, `gdp per capita`, and `average` (gdp per capita per region per year) for 2015 for countries with gdp above average for their region (should be NLD, IRQ, USA).
The result should look something like this:

```
  code  year  gdp per capita    average
3  NLD  2015        45175.23  24564.015
7  IRQ  2015         4688.32   2633.395
9  USA  2015        56863.37  50249.235
```

I wanted to try this in Python because I recently completed an introductory course to SQL and was amazed at the simplicity of the solution in SQL. While I managed to make it work in Python, it seems overly complicated to me. Is there any way to achieve the same result with less code or without the need for .groupby and helper columns? Please see my solution below.

```
data = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="inner", on="code")

grouper = data.groupby(["region", "year"])["gdp per capita"].mean().reset_index()

for i in range(len(data)):
  average = (grouper.loc[(grouper["year"] == data.loc[i, "year"]) & (grouper["region"] == data.loc[i, "region"]), "gdp per capita"]).to_list()[0]
  data.loc[i, "average"] = average


result = data.loc[(data["year"] == 2015) & (data["gdp per capita"] > data["average"]), ["code", "year", "gdp per capita", "average"]]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loops are basically *never* the right answer when it comes to pandas.

```
# This is your join and where clause.
df = df1.merge(df2, on='code')[lambda x: x.year.eq(2015)]
# This is your aggregate function.
df['average'] = df.groupby(['region'])['gdp per capita'].transform('mean')
# This is your select and having clause.
out = df[df['gdp per capita'].gt(df['average'])][['code', 'year', 'gdp per capita', 'average']]
print(out)
```

Output:

```
  code  year  gdp per capita    average
3  NLD  2015        45175.23  24564.015
7  IRQ  2015         4688.32   2633.395
9  USA  2015        56863.37  50249.235
```